# Redirect output of Python program to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, python, stdout

I have a Python executable, written and compiled by somebody else, that I simply need to run once halfway down my own bash script. The program uses a text-based UI, therefore waits for input before proceeding, but the key operations it performs when starting are required in my bash script. A messy (and strange) procedure I know, but unfortunately I haven't got any other options.

I've gotten around forcefully closing the program with a kill signal, but the program's TUI insists on outputting to wherever it's run. I've tried redirecting both stdout and stderr to /dev/null and running the program in the background by suffixing an ampersand, but simply can't get it to play ball. I believe the cause is the program spawns other processes, and the output redirection of the parent process doesn't affect them. Is there any trick I can utilise to redirect all output from child processes too?

Comment: Python is typically not compiled.  Are you sure you don't have the source code?

Comment: I thought it was unusual, but the file is definitely binary - nor can I find source code anywhere on the machine. Two child processes that the program runs are pyo2.2 and python2.2, which was how I assumed I was dealing with Python.

Comment: What does `file /path/to/progname` tell you?

Answer (score 3):

The program may be writing to the tty instead of stdout. You may be able to use the `unbuffer`  script that comes with [`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/) or some other technique using `expect` or something similar.

Here's a demonstration. Create this script and call it "writetty". Then do `chmod u+x writetty`:

```
#!/bin/bash
date > /dev/tty
```

Now try it out:

```
$ ./writetty
Tue Jun  8 12:24:36 CDT 2010
$ ./writetty > /dev/null
Tue Jun  8 12:24:46 CDT 2010
$ var=$(./writetty)
Tue Jun  8 12:24:56 CDT 2010
$ unbuffer ./writetty > /tmp/writetty.out
$ cat /tmp/writetty.out
Tue Jun  8 12:25:06 CDT 2010
$ var=$(unbuffer ./writetty)
$ echo $var
Tue Jun  8 12:25:16 CDT 2010
```

You could use `expect` to respond to the program's request for input instead of killing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Isn't the line "./writetty > /dev/null" equivalent to "date > /dev/tty > /dev/null" in your example? That line successfully suppresses output - so can we assume the Python prog isn't outputting to /dev/tty? I'd love to be able to use expect, but I'm not authorised to install any additional packages :(

Comment: @STM: No, they're not equivalent. As you can see from the demo (try it yourself), redirecting the script to `/dev/null` still outputs to the terminal.

Comment: @STM: You might also try: `yourprog < /dev/null > /dev/null` or `yourprog < /dev/tty > /dev/null` or `yourprog < /dev/stdin > /dev/null` to see if that will get its attention.